# Is there a Python standard library function to create a generator from repeatedly calling a functional?

Tags: python, generator

I have a method want to call repeatedly to iterate over, which will raise a `StopIteration` when it's done (in this case an instance of pyarrow.csv.CSVStreamingReader looping over a large file). I can use it in a for loop like this:

```
def batch_generator():
    while True:
        try:
            yield reader.read_next_batch()
        except StopIteration:
            return

for batch in batch_generator():
    writer.write_table(batch)
```

It can be done in a generic way with a user-defined function:

```
def make_generator(f):
    def gen():
        while True:
            try:
                yield f()
            except StopIteration:
                return
    
    return gen()

for batch in make_generator(reader.read_next_batch):
    writer.write_table(batch)
```

...but I wondered if something like this was possible with standard library functions or with some obscure syntax?

Comment: What's wrong with just `while True: writer.write_table(reader.read_next_batch())`?

Comment: You have to manually catch the `StopIteration`

Comment: What `StopIteration`? Isn't `read_next_batch()` a function returning a value? If you have `StopIteration` then your problem is solved - just use a `for` loop...

Comment: You are correct, I was was missing the `iter` call in Chronial's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would assume that the [normal `iter()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) with its second argument should do what you want. As in:

```
for batch in iter(reader.read_next_batch, None):
    ...
```

Comment: Well now I feel silly... I was missing the None before, is there an explanation of why that's needed?

Comment: `iter` is a weird function. It's basically two different functions, with the number of arguments determining what it actually does. `iter(f, x)` is a sequence of values produced by `f()`, until `f()` returns `x`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your underlying question of how to iterate a CSVStreamingReader is: The [`CSVStreamingReader`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.csv.CSVStreamingReader.html#pyarrow.csv.CSVStreamingReader) is iterable and does [just the thing you want](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/0dfe59223c4b59f3f663fc0ee6d164a3670ef747/python/pyarrow/ipc.pxi#L537-L542):

```
reader = pyarrow.csv.open_csv(...)
for batch in reader:
    ...
```

In general it is really rare for python libraries to return "iterable" things that are not python-iterable. That is always a sensible first thing to try.

Comment: Thanks, it's actually not in the docs (https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.csv.CSVStreamingReader.html) suprisingly.

Comment: Yeah, I was also confused about that. That's why I had a look at the source code.